# Android Facebook Native ads error: 1001 no fill

Tags: android, facebook, native-ads

I am getting the error `1001 No Fill` when trying to load **real ads** for testing. I'm able to load **test ads** by adding `AdSettings.addTestDevice(deviceId);` and have fulfilled the steps as per [Facebook testing guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/testing):

- Native Facebook Apps installed in device
- Developer/tester account logged into the native Facebook app
- Logged in with Facebook account in my app
- Deselected "Opt out of interest-based ads" in Google ads setting

It also mentioned that we are able to test with **real ads** on testing stage and it is a more recommended method. Why am I still getting the error? Is there any other possible factor causing the failure to test with **real ads**?

Comment: I am getting the same error.

Comment: Have you resolved the problem? I also have the same error

Comment: It was long ago, remember I've waited for some time to see the real ads appear, maybe you can contact Facebook support to confirm the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem you describe. In my case, the `Facebook` app in my device is not installed from Google Play (it is installed by Samsung as default app). My suggestion:

- If the Facebook app in your phone can't uninstall, that means it is pre-installed as system app, go to `Settings->Apps->Facebook` and find the menu *Uninstall updates*, then go to Google Play and install latest update.
- Or try your app (request real Ad) in other physical device, and make sure the Facebook app is download in Google Play and developer account has been logged in.
- make sure your payment methods is currect in your facebook account.